# Odoo 10EE try to click the Mark as to do (STAR) or UNSTAR button it does not work

Tags: email, odoo, odoo-10

on odoo 10ee, in the Discuss app, when i try to click the Mark as to do (STAR) or UNSTAR button it does not work, but if i click once and refresh then it is marked or unmarked.

Strange, any suggestions?

thanks

Comment: As it is an enterprise edition, you can add a issue in odoo and they will fix it ASAP

Comment: let me try that

Answer (score 0):

okay for future reference:
I had the longpolling port set, BUT if you dont set number of workers as i havent, the longpolling will NOT work.
So, final answer, set the longpolling port and add workers = number_of_workers_per_need in the odoo.conf file
cheers